# Default styling differing between localhost and local IP on Chrome 61

Tags: css, google-chrome, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack dev server to play with a little front end project and I am experiencing different default styling when accessing a project on localhost as opposed to accessing it via my local IP.

Does anyone have an explanation for why this might be?

Chrome Version: Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Webpack dev server version: 2.6.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any external css involved in your code?

Comment: No CSS at all...

Comment: Cached style info?  ctrl+f5.

Comment: No, there are no cached styles.